# Hyperlink inside iframe is not working when I click on the parent page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink in iframe, when I click this on the parent page, is not working.

Here is an example set up:

**iframe.html**

```
<h1>I'm inner page!</h1>
<a id="shared" class="btn" href="pc.html" target="_top">go another page</a>
```

**parent.html**

```
<h1>I'm INDEX</h1>
<iframe id="open" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="iframe.html" width="100%" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"></iframe>
```

please help me T__T

Comment: The `sandbox` attribute of the iframe is missing either `allow-top-navigation` or `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation`, for this to be _allowed_ to work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

Comment: No wonder! I got it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove target attribute

```html
<h1>I'm inner page!</h1>
<a id="shared" class="btn" href="pc.html">go another page</a>
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp